# How to disallow login for inactive users in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have an active field on the users collection and I want to prevent the users with that field set to false to login on the application. I could allow them to login in the future, so I can't delete their account or change their password. How can I disallow them to login in meteor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this does not stop them from logging in directly it will logout them out as soon as they login which depending on the your use may work as a hack around:

```
Meteor.autorun(function(){
  if(typeof Meteor.user().blocked !== "undefined"){
    Meteor.logout(function(){alert('Your account is blocked at the moment, please contact us for more information');});    
  }
});
```

Where blocked is the invalid account attribute you have set

Comment: **Warning:** this method work, but inactive users could login using the browser console and this method will not prevent that. At start of every publication, check if the user is inactive, so inactive users can't see application data. You must also check if the user is inactive on create, update and delete operations, because they can be made using the console.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the safest thing to do is to move the user's data to another collection and delete the user's account. Of course that may not be desirable if existing data in the system is linked to that user's id.

I looked through the docs and couldn't find anything that sounded like you could set an account invalidation flag (this seems like it would be a really useful feature though).

**Warning I am not a security expert. The following advice could be awful:**

If you need to leave the user account in place, one thing you could try is moving or modifying the SRP data in the user's account. For example you could just append the string `'--disabled--'` to the `'services.password.srp.salt'`. That will prevent the user from logging back in and clearly you can reverse the process just by removing the string.